# News Show Pro GK5 pagination

Tags: joomla, module, pagination, joomla2.5

I am using the following module extension in Joomla 3.0 to display articles: https://www.gavick.com/news-show-pro
The module displays articles in columns and slides to the next article on automation or with pagination buttons.

Problem: It always slides by the nr of columns.

Example: If you specify 4 columns and paginate it slides away those 4 columns to the next 4.
Is there an option which allows me to just slide one column away and display a new one at the end.

Comment: Pro extension = Pro support. Please contact the developer

Comment: "Pro extension"? Excuse me but if you would have read what the website states it's obviously clear that it's not a pro version: "An amazing free Joomla module that creates the ultimate showcase for your content"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this will not be added to the extension. Here is the belonging github issue:

https://github.com/GavickPro/News-Show-Pro-GK5/issues/214

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the initial comment. Looked too quickly at the word "Pro".

This isn't a default feature with this module, however some core jquery hacks can be made to the module, although I'm not a fan of some sort of approach and would suggest using a different module. Below os a little something to get you started.

Firstly ensure you are using the jQuery engine rather than MooTools. To to this, in the Module setting, go to the **External Files** tab and set the **Used Javascript Framework** to **jQuery**.

Go to line **275** of the following the following file:

```
modules\mod_news_pro_gk5\interface\scripts\engine.jquery.js
```

where you will find this code:

```
jQuery($this.module.find('.nspArtScroll2')).animate({
        'margin-left': (-1 * this.arts_current * this.arts_block_width) + "%"
}, $this.config['animation_speed']);
```

and replace it with the following:

```
var contentWidth = jQuery('.nspArt').width();
jQuery($this.module.find('.nspArtScroll2')).animate({
        'margin-left': "-" + contentWidth + "px"
}, $this.config['animation_speed']);
```

You will now notice that the slide moves 1 article at a time, however the previous ones disappear. This is because of the `active` class. Only articles within the parent element with the class `active` are set to be visible. From here on, have a mess around with the CSS to set the visibility styling.

Hope this helps

Comment: I came across this file. The usage of the active class seems indeed to be the problem here. It needs to be attached to the child nspArt divs. Also your contentWidth variable does not take into account that it might be possible that each element might have a different width.

Comment: From what I saw, it looked like the width of each container was equal and they were divided up equally. I could be wrong. I'll take a look again later on to confirm